# OpenGraph Objects with different sub-domains

Tags: subdomain, facebook-opengraph

Each of our developers has his/her own subdomain, for development purposes, e.g.

```
http://fred.oursite.com
http://joe.oursite.com
http://www.oursite.com
```

We currently have a Facebook App which we share between all these different subdomains without any problems.

However open graph seems to be really strict about domain names for the "og:url", and it doesn't seem to allow any kind of matching for subdomains. This is a drag on development - our process is to completely isolate the 'live' and 'dev' sites. It would be great if there was a feature allowing us to specify a list of domains?

Anyone with different Country-specific TLDs will surely be given a headache if they separate things between their different domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of my environments (dev1, dev2, test, prod), we have a separate app configured.  It's a pain but it's the only good way to make it work.