# Open Graph approval, Using staging site for action approval submission without changing app URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

hi I have a site that is already running. which uses regular facebook posting actions.
I have built a new version which contains open graph. now I need to approve the actions before I can upload this version to production. I have a staging site which seats in a subdomain.

```
http://staging.mysite.com
```

my facebook app is of course pointed to: `http://www.mysite.com`
posting open graph action in my staging ENV doesn't seem to work..
how can I approve the actions on this production app? (can't switch the app URL to staging because then my production stuff won't work)

please help 
thanks

Comment: _“doesn’t seem to work”_ is not a good problem description. Please be more specific.

Comment: I post my actions. facebook is not returning an error. but it also won't show that action (for both users who are admins on that app or devlopers of that app)

Comment: according to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757606/opengraph-objects-with-different-sub-domains then it won't work on subdomains.. anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this question had already been succesfully answered here

[Submitting new OpenGraph Action for review without deploying it to the live environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743550/submitting-new-opengraph-action-for-review-without-deploying-it-to-the-live-envi)