# Submitting new OpenGraph Action for review without deploying it to the live environment

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, review, test-environments

I am running a website with OpenGraph actions, which has two separate Facebook Apps associated with it (a "live" and "approval" app).

This allows us to make breaking changes to the app during development without affecting live.

I have now made one such breaking change, and need it submitting to the live, however I cannot publish it to the live environment until the OpenGraph action is approved (because it is, by definition, a breaking change).

I have clones of both the action on both the approval server and live, and both systems are, in essence, identical (except the updated code and some extra error reporting).

Would it be acceptable by Facebook to submit the action for review via the approval server, using the approval app for the verdict on the action in the main app action to be accepted?

In previous cases it was not an issue with them testing the actions on live because Facebook integration was not yet enabled (so it wouldn't break any existing functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make changes to your open graph actions, they will not be available to your end users until they are approved. This means your users will be able to use your "non-broken" actions, even if you make any breaking changes to them.

[Further Reading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/#resubmit)

Another scenario (which is pretty obvious but I would still like to state):

If you have breaking changes in your **application code** that you dont want to deploy, you can create a staging environment and deploy your site there. So, for action approval you will submit staging server's address to facebook approval team. This will require that your staging server must have access to the app. This means your staging environment must be a sub domain of your production. Eg. lets say your production is www.example.com, then your staging should be staging.example.com.

Hope this helps.